# BigQuery for Google Analytics Export combining ANDs and ORs for visits with specific hits.page.pagePath doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the figures related to search performance based on goal completions in Google Analytics.This goals are based on urls, so as a first step what I did was getting the total completions adding as many ORs as goal urls we have and that's fine. So far so good.

The problem is when we have to segment it by "visits with search". Based on url as well: pagepath like "%search_parameter%"  but this time in a separate statement as the previous goal urls:

```
SELECT sum(totals.visits)
FROM [XXXXXX.ga_sessions_20150101]
WHERE 

(
 REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/goal1/')
 or REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/goal2/')
 or REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/goal3/')
 or REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/goal4/')
)
and REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/search/')
```

In Google Analytics interface of course I have goals completed from people doing searches, so I don't understand what may have been missing when constructing this query.

Any help?

Many Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "visits with search", and how would you use the url?

Comment: Hi Pentium10, we define "Visits with search"  as visits with at least 1 pageview to a url containing "/search/". Hence the last line in the code above "and REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/search/')"

Comment: Have you seen the Cookbook? You can find ideas there: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en#query6_SequenceOfHits

Comment: Thanks Pentium10, yes I saw the Cookbok but anything about this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood that "visits with search" mean that at least one url in hits.page.pagePath matches '/search/', then I think the following should work for you:

```
    SELECT sum(totals.visits)
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
       totals.visits, 
       hits.page.PagePath,
       SOME(REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath,r'/search/')) 
          WITHIN RECORD AS has_search
    FROM [XXXXXX.ga_sessions_20150101]
    WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath,r'[/goal1/|/goal2/|/goal3/|/goal4/]')
   )
   WHERE has_search
```

Comment: Hi Mosha, many thanks for your response. Interesting this "WITHIN THE RECORD" usage, I had never seen it! But unfortunately anything is returned using this query.

Comment: I received another query version with some explanations and it works properly. The results are the same as the once I have from unsampled reports:

Comment: `SELECT
COUNT(1) AS goalCompletions_from_visits_w_search
FROM
(  -- query 2
  SELECT
  fullVisitorId,  visitNumber,  
  SUM(conversions) AS conversions,
  SUM(searches) AS searches
  FROM
  (  
    -- query 1  
    SELECT  fullVisitorId, visitNumber,  
    IF (REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath,r'[/goal1/|/goal2/|/goal3/|/goal4/]') , 1, null) AS conversions,  
    IF (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath,r'/search'), 1, null) AS searches 
  
   FROM  [xxxxxx.ga_sessions_20150101] 

  )  
    GROUP EACH BY fullVisitorId, visitNumber )  
WHERE conversions IS NOT NULL  
AND   searches    IS NOT NULL`